# iptables-mod-tee to monitor outgoing traffic from a WAN interface

Tags: linux, iptables, openwrt, iptables-redirect

[image]

I have an OpenWrt router (v18.06.5, r7897-9d401013fc), that does a standard (out of the box) NAT between a `192.168.0.1/24` LAN (on `eth1`) and one public IP `140.82.118.4` (on `eth2`).  The router has the `iptables-mod-tee` module loaded and running.

My goal is to monitor the traffic going OUT of the interface `eth2` to the WAN. The monitoring is to be done by a computer running "Wireshark", which is located on the LAN (at `192.168.0.3`).

For example when I `ping 8.8.8.8` from another computer on the LAN (e.g. from `192.168.0.2`), I expect to see an IP/ICMP Echo request, that has `ip.src` == `140.82.118.4` and `ip.dst` == `8.8.8.8` going out on the `eth2` interface to the WAN.

I am using the following command to modify the iptables to send the cloned packets to the host running the "Wireshark":
`iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.0.3`

It works but "Wireshark" displays the IP/ICMP Echo request with `ip.src` == `192.168.0.2` and `ip.dst` == `8.8.8.8`...which is wrong, because the `ip.src` looks like it would be before it is SNAT'ed (or Masqueraded) !!!

The `ip.src` should be `140.82.118.4` which is the IP of my public WAN interface... because if it wasn't, then the `8.8.8.8 host` would not know where to send the ICMP Echo reply to, however the ping command is getting  ICMP Echo replies from the `8.8.8.8` host (as it should).

Why is this happening and how to correct it ?

Comment: on which hardware are you running openwrt ?

Comment: The Netgear R7800 ( ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v7l), arm_cortex-a15_neon-vfpv4 ).  See 
https://openwrt.org/toh/netgear/r7800

Answer (score 0):

The rule in mangle's POSTROUTING is ran early than rule in nat's POSTROUTING...so Source NAT is not happened when you do TEE operation in mangle's POSTROUTING ....
see below attached iptables diagram: https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.aa2afe9a3c09b762af0b59c8670c7740?rik=SvxGxvrwso1veg&riu=http%3a%2f%2flinux-ip.net%2fnf%2fnfk-traversal.png&ehk=kT6op7%2bDt4yCPX1npGPAw9mWOpRiFTZsA5qJ0HMDQZo%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0

[image: iptables diagram]

Comment: Your informational post offers no solution. This site is for solutions, but you have just pointed them to information. OP is asking Why and how to fix. Please revise your answer.